# Cannot convert void to ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon), and actually I'm trying to learn how to display the window after minimize it in the tray. So when the user double click on the icon, the window should appear again. Actually I've created this code:

```
private void MetroWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TaskbarIcon tbi = new TaskbarIcon();
   tbi.DoubleClickCommand = Recover(tbi);

     switch (WindowState)
     {
         case WindowState.Minimized:
            Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            tbi.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
     }
}

private void Recover(TaskbarIcon tbi)
{
    tbi.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

How you can see when I minimize the window the icon in the tray appear. This working pretty well. I've declared the icon like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Utils.Resources.UIDictionary"
                xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar">

<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"
              IconSource="/Utils/Images/Test.ico"
              ToolTipText="hello world" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now the problem is that on this line: `tbi.DoubleClickCommand = Recover(tbi);` I get this error:

> Cannot convert the type void in System.Windows.Input.ICommand

It's not possible call a method in this way? Why?

Comment: I suggest you read up on WPF in general, especially MVVM and the Command pattern. If you treat it as if it were WinForms, you could as well use WinForms.

Comment: @nvoigt well I'm a bit rusty actually on wpf

Comment: To address the actual problem: `DoubleClickCommand` is an `ICommand`. You're calling `Recover` which returns a `void` and trying to assign that void to something (which never makes sense). Furthermore, to do this, you've created a new `TaskbarIcon` that is always local to the `MetroWindow_StateChanged` function. It's never added to the UI, so nothing you do to it matters. I'm not familiar with metro apps, so I'm not sure how to get the `TaskbarIcon` from your UI that you actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for a simple RelayCommand that is what you need

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> action;
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

and then, like the other answer its just

```
tbi.DoubleClickCommand =new RelayCommand(_ => Recover(tbi));
```

Comment: because you dont get one as standard in WPF

Comment: @DeanChalk Okay, now is clear, I thought that `RelayCommand` was a class of c#, thanks for the nice example :)

Comment: it is a class @Dillinger

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Bad explaination, I mean was a c# features

Comment: we have to add dll reference to use which exists in the namespace i mentioned

Comment: @DeanChalk I don't know if is a problem of the code, but when I double click on the icon in the tray the event isn't fired, any suggestion? :\

Comment: The RelayCommand code is correct. I suggest putting a breakpoint in the 'Execute(object parameter)' method of the RelayCommand and see if the command is being fired properly. If not, something else is consuming the double-click. If the breakpoint is being hit then your Recover method need investigation

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `DoubleClickCommand` is of type [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You need to set it as [`RelayCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand(v=vs.110).aspx) which is subtype of `ICommand` for it to compile like:

```
 tbi.DoubleClickCommand =new RelayCommand(param => Recover(tbi));
```

You can read more about Relay Commands [on this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Comment: Uhm, I don't understand a thing, when I paste your code the compiler underline `RelayCommand` and display: `RelayCommand was not found.` I've no using available in the intellisense, what's happean?

Comment: probably you are missing the namespace ``Microsoft.TeamFoundation.MVVM``

Comment: you need to include the using statement for the namespace